# Visual Studio 2015 XAML Designer doesn't display localized strings

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have some applications designed in XAML for WP8 and for Windows Desktop with localized strings by using Appresources.resx and AppResources.xx.resx files.

In VS 2013 XAML designer, all localized strings are displayed correctly.

In VS 2015 XAML designer, all strings are shown as empty, I have no error and when executed, the localized strings are displayed normally, the problem occurs only in design mode.

I would like to migrate all my VS2013 projects to VS2015 but I just can't because of this issue.

Is there a setting or a workaround to solve this?

Edit :

I've uninstalled then reinstalled my VS2015 Pro and now all my strings are displayed by their name but not their values... Not very usefull but better than nothing!